# Why do we have an "error" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-block-request

I note that we have a [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) tag in the main site and it doesn't mean anything on its own. When last checked, it has over 280+ questions tagged as such. Manually editing them out of all of those questions is soo Jorge-Castro like and I thought I would open a meta post to discuss it.

So, do we keep the tag or just blacklist it?

Comment: After a quick scan of the tag many of those should be bug reports and not questions here.

Comment: First of all, since when has it been against the rules to be Jorge Castro-like and edit ALLLLL the things? Anyway, what @JorgeCastro said is true.

Comment: Related Thread: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2541/request-burnination-of-error-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because someone with enough reputation created it and then none have been bothered to do anything about it. A lot of new users will probably use this misleading tag.

a lot of the questions on the site are errors, but adding that they are errors isn't helpful.