# Request: Burnination and Blacklisting of [error] tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags

One of the most overly used tags in the site is [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error).  In almost every case, there are many other tags which are far more descriptive.

All 303 questions using that tag aside, I believe the tag should be purged and blacklisted.  I would like everyone else's opinion, however this is a very strong recommendation.

[image]

Related Threads:
http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2363/why-do-we-have-an-error-tag

Comment: You can probably add `freeze` to this too.

Comment: @JorgeCastro `date` could probably be included as well... but there's a thousand of these tags that need purging with fire, so...

Comment: That's why I collected them here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/184/tag-synonym-suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Burn it down as deserved, most issues that contain errors will be associated with it and the tag does not help sorting out specifically what is the issue about.

I mean [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) will be used for [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless), [compiling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compiling), [application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application), [apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apt-get) and other more. What kind of separation or usefulness does it provide?

Does anyone really subscribe to [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) as one of their favorite tags?

Comment: I don't have it as a favorite tag, but I do have the RSS feed in Google Reader. :P (then again, I have all sorts of weird tags in RSS so thats not really an indicator of anything)

Comment: @jrg `so thats not really an indicator of anything` > Just like the tag then ;)

Answer (score -1):

*note: I'm playing devils advocate here, because while I partially agree with this, **I also think the tag is bad.***

While I agree that it is a bad tag, I like it to some extent, because most of the questions in that tag are actually bugs, and thus off-topic.

Its almost childs play to stop bugs/off-topic stuff *when* we have a tag that 90% of off-topic questions are going to use.

Comment: Doesn't that equate to the definition of a 'meta tag' in the sense that its purpose does not exist?  in theory, having a tag that consists of questions which can work in 30 thousand other tags, is bad form, even if it does help catch offtopic questions.

Comment: @ThomasWard In theory yes. However, we can edit those that don't belong there and aren't off-topic, but I'm all in favor of keeping it around if we can kill off-topic stuff easily - because to be blunt, we can't stop it from getting on the site in the first place, and as I said, having it in one place will help. A lot.

Comment: just to point out, this already has two upvotes, so i think there's more people who agree with me on this :P

Comment: One is mine, and I up voted because I think it's a good question that needs to be hashed out. I'm merely offering my point of view. :)