# The 'error' tag should be blacklisted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-block-request

The [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) tag:

- is general
- is ambiguous
- describes *over* half of the questions on Ask Ubuntu
- is misleading
- could mean boot errors, graphical errors, errors seen in the terminal, etc.
- If the `error` tag is used to describe a non-supported package from separate PPAs or not in a PPA at all, there would be no one to help and Ask Ubuntu would be the wrong place anyway.
- is general
- is also general
- Did I mention the [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) tag is general?

Point is, this tag is too general to be useful in any situation at all. Please blacklist this tag for the sake of Ask Ubuntu's usefulness.

Answer (score 3):

This tag is far too tenacious. The links seen on thing page point to its recurring attack, and it is just too general. However, I fear that blacklisting it could open tags like [error-handling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error-handling) up to misuse for general errors, not specifically error handlers. In fact, it already is being a little mishandled(no bad pun intended) in this way.

Comment: I quite agree with this problem, however I can't very many people misusing that tag, and the error tag in the first place isn't used enough to pose a big enough problem.

Answer (score -3):

We don't generally blacklist tags just because they shouldn't exist. It's only if they're being pervasively and wrongly used that blacklisting is considered. There were only two questions tagged [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error). I retagged them. While I agree this is a terrible tag, I don't see how it's worth blacklisting.

Comment: There is [another question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2363/why-do-we-have-an-error-tag?rq=1) that gives me proof that this tag was purged at least once. "When last checked, it has over 280+ questions tagged as such."

Comment: And there's [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2541/request-burnination-and-blacklisting-of-error-tag) one too.  I agree, this tag should definitely go!

Comment: @user1610406 You're saying this tag should be blacklisted because it had 280 questions once, was purged ....and then sprung back up, in just the short span of a year, with all of 2 questions? Am I missing something?

Comment: yep, this one is always on cleanup lists, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3343/summer-cleanup-feedback-wanted-etc

Comment: @EliahKagan It's a useless tag, and it keeps getting recreated.

Comment: I guess the point of blacklisting is to prevent a tag from being recreated after it gets cleaned up & retagged.

Comment: I'm [starting to change my mind](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6055/22949) about this.